# StrongTypingException при создании модели из Базы Данных

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

Продолжаю мучать Entity. Создаю модель MySQL БД. После того как выбираю в мастере EDM нужные таблицы и жму `Готово` падает ошибка  такого содержания :

> При создании модели произошло непредвиденное исключение. 
>   "StrongTypingException": значение столбца Isprimerykey в таблице TableDetails равно DBnull.

Никакой `TableDetails` у меня нет. С чем связано исключение, как его исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На [Stackoverflow на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33575109/mysql-entity-the-value-for-column-isprimarykey-in-table-tabledetails-is) утверждают, что это [баг](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79163) и предлагают менять настройки БД

Comment: @defaultlocale создал таблицу как там написано - не помогло

Comment: Что значит создал таблицу? Там предлагают перезапустить MySQL и установить настройку для всей базы.

Comment: @defaultlocale где? там 5 пунктов описаны и первым же `1. Create a sample database with a sample table:`

Comment: ааа, Вы читаете багрепорт, там шаги по воспроизведению бага. Прочитайте [ответ на Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35422569/451518).

Comment: @defaultlocale спасибо помогло!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В [обсуждении на Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33575109/mysql-entity-the-value-for-column-isprimarykey-in-table-tabledetails-is) на английском утверждают, что это [известная ошибка в коннекторе для MySQL](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79163). Ошибка не устранена, но предлагается следующее решение:

- перезапустить MySQL;
- отключить для БД настройку оптимизации derived_merge. Для этого в командной строке MySQL выполните следующие команды:

  ```
  use <<имя БД>>;
  set global optimizer_switch='derived_merge=OFF';
  ```
- создать/обновить модель.